# Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

The app crashes as soon as it gets installed and throws the weird error above.
I have annotated the activity as shown below as well as its child fragments.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
    class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        companion object{
           lateinit var currentUser: User
        }
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
            val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.home_nav)
            val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
            bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
            fetchCurrentUser()
        }
```

Also attaching the Application class which is mandatory for every app using Hilt as per the documentation

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class CoreApplication:Application()
```

and the logcat of the crash

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application. Found: class androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.createComponent(ActivityComponentManager.java:82)
        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager.generatedComponent(ActivityComponentManager.java:65)
        at com.example.vcare.home.Hilt_HomeActivity.generatedComponent(Hilt_HomeActivity.java:43)
        at com.example.vcare.home.Hilt_HomeActivity.inject(Hilt_HomeActivity.java:62)
        at com.example.vcare.home.Hilt_HomeActivity.onCreate(Hilt_HomeActivity.java:37)
        at com.example.vcare.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
```

Comment: Have you declared your App in the AndroidManifest.xml? Please write "anroid:name =.CoreApplication" in your XML.

Comment: @Andrew works fine now,all thanks to you

Comment: Glad I could help, would be nice If you could accept the answer then.

Comment: ofc man,thanks again

Comment: I have same issue on a multimodule architecture in the feature module when i use @androidEntryPoint on a feature Activity . Any solution?

Comment: Hi, I;m also facing the same issue over multimodule, app and presentation module
app contains Application class with @HiltAndroidApp and presentation has Launhcer Main Activity, in manifest of app module mentioned Applicaiton, in presentation manifest added launcher but no application class is empty. how to do so?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The solution to this problem was: Declare `android:name = ".CoreApplication"` in your *AndroidManifest.xml* file, in the `<application .../>`tag.

Comment: Perfect Solution

Comment: The above code should be added to the <application tag in manifest.

Comment: To add to this, make sure your test package name in your test manifest under `src/androidTest` differs from the one in your `src/main`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I faced an error with implementing a repository into the ViewModel class.

I followed some fixes to resolve the errors.

1. Adding entry point to activity class (**AndroidEntryPoint**)
2. Adding entry point to application class (**HiltAndroidApp**)
3. Adding name to manifest application **android:name=".main.BaseApplication"**
4. Adding **@Inject** to repository class

Now issue with Hilt with MVVM and clean architecture are resolved!

Answer (score 5):

Declare your Application class in manifest by adding the following:

```xml
   <application
        android:name=".CoreApplication"
        ....
   />
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was slightly different: in my main module I only needed Hilt for the Application class, so I only added the hilt-android dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta'
```

Which resulted in the above error message.

What I forgot was to also add the compile dependency to the app module:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.33-beta'
```

This solved the problem, as I was missing the generated class.

Answer (score 0):

Added field inside Manifest Application tag like below

```
    <application
...
    android:name=".core.HiltApplication"
    >
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add @Merlin jaykumar answer
i missed the below annotation on View model

```
@HiltViewModel
```

Example:-

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authUseCases: AuthenticationUseCases
) : ViewModel() {
```

Answer (score 0):

People who are working on Hilt with Multimodular architecture and still facing the issue here's the resolution

These were my modules

app, core (data, domain), presentation

dependency

```
app -> core, presentation
core -> data, domain
presentation -> core
```

Now I thought the domain already has hilt in gradle so I can just convert `implementation` into `api` so app module can still use hilt but I found out This was not working and giving me the above issue.

So This was my way of solving the issue

app>Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="false" // Important
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
    </application>
```

app> build.gradle

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

dependencies {

    //hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.50")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.1.0")

}
```

app> Application.kt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : Application() {
}
```

top level build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.50" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13" apply false
    }
```

Presentation > MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    }
```

Presentation> MyViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getDataUseCase: GetDataUseCase
) : ViewModel() {}
```

And inside

core>hiltModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object hiltModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesMyRepository(): MyRepository {
        return MyRepositoryImpl()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesGetDataUseCase(myRepository: MyRepository): GetDataUseCase {
        return GetDataUseCase(myRepository)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
    android:name="package.YourApplicationClass"  <--------
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="xyz"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I've added this declearation to manifest and solved my problem.