# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application Found: class dv.file.transh.app.FileExplorer

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

The app crashes as soon as it gets installed and throws the weird error above

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgB1q.png)

and the logcat of the crash

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJPiu.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006085/hilt-activity-must-be-attached-to-an-androidentrypoint-application)

Comment: No i try all of them but it's not working

Comment: replace images with text

Comment: okay .you have any solution ?

Comment: Include the code for your `FileExplorer` class in your question.

Comment: I already added a code

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your Application class in the manifest?

```xml
   <application
        android:name=".HiltApplication"
        ....
   />
```

Comment: yes i declare  **android:name="dv.file.transh.app.FileExplorer"**