# Hilt: under which circumstances can an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity NOT be attached to a Hilt App?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

*It was really hard to come up with a proper title for that one... As a disclaimer, this is NOT a dupe of [Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006085/hilt-activity-must-be-attached-to-an-androidentrypoint-application).* Hilt is v. 2.44.

We are seeing some very rare crashes (around 40 users out of several hundred thousand active users, not reproducible on our side) with the root cause reported as:

> Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be
> attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify
> your Application's class name in your manifest's 's
> android:name attribute?

According to the Play Console, the crash happens repeatedly for the same users as the number of events is around 8x the number of affected users.

The crash happens in the launcher Activity of the app and obviously there's everything fine with the Hilt setup. The exception is thrown in the `dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ActivityComponentManager` class, here:

```
protected Object createComponent() {
  if (!(activity.getApplication() instanceof GeneratedComponentManager)) {
    if (Application.class.equals(activity.getApplication().getClass())) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
              "Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. "
              + "Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your manifest's "
              + "<application />'s android:name attribute?");
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Hilt Activity must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Application. Found: "
            + activity.getApplication().getClass());
  }

  return EntryPoints.get(
          activityRetainedComponentManager, ActivityComponentBuilderEntryPoint.class)
      .activityComponentBuilder()
      .activity(activity)
      .build();
}
```

The condition `!(activity.getApplication() instanceof GeneratedComponentManager)` is obviously true which leads me to believe that the Application class returned here by `activity.getApplication()` in those rare cases is actually something different than our real Application annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`.

Any ideas on how this is possible, considering the crash does not happen for 99.9% of the users? I didn't find anything related in the Hilt changelog and also no issues that would mentions that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this: it looks like those crashes are caused by a backup-related [bug in Android](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160946170) that is still not fixed despite the status suggesting otherwise. See [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2584) Dagger issue and also [that](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/748) one.

Currently known workarounds:

- disable backups
- switch to a [key-value backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup)
- terminate your launcher activity in onCreate when you detect restricted mode (will most likely break backups): `if(application !is YourApplicationSubclass) exitProcess(0)`